# disassemble managed binary to get .cs code

Tags: .net, instrumentation

Is this possible?
I have a binary that throws an access violation exception when instrumented. 
I want to step through instrumented code, so I need to generate source code of the instrumented code.
Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot step through "instrumented code", only the machine code that gets generated from it.  Your description is *far* too vague to recommend anything to look at the IL.

Answer (score 6):

[.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is closest to what you want.

**update:**
As pointed out in comments, Reflector works on static assemblies, not runtime assemblies so it may not be able to get the instrumented code.  Maybe Reflector Pro or a plugin can do it, but I don't know since I have never needed that capablility.

Comment: There are several Reflector plugins that not only generate the code but also provide project files, etc.

Comment: I don't think Reflector does instrumented assemblies, only static. CMIIW.

Comment: @adrian godong: That's why I said its closest to what he wants :)  I will clarify my answer.